# Cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection' to 'MyProject.Models.EditViewModel'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model, edit

I get two following errors in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project:

> Error 1 The best overloaded method match for
>   'SklepAlfa.Models.ProduktyController.Edytuj(int,
>   SklepAlfa.Models.ProduktyEdytujViewModel)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection' to
>   'SklepAlfa.Models.ProduktyEdytujViewModel'

Here is my ProduktyEdytujViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using SklepAlfa.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SklepAlfa.Models
{
    public class ProduktyEdytujViewModel
    {
        public Produkty Produkt { get; set; }
        public int id_produktu { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Kategorie_produktow> Kategorie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

And here it is used in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edytuj(int id) //Edit
    {
        var model = new ProduktyEdytujViewModel //ProductsEditViewModel
        {
            Produkt = sklepBaza.PobierzProduktWgId(id), //GetProductById
            Kategorie = sklepBaza.PobierzKategorieProduktow() //GetProductCategories
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edytuj(int id, ProduktyEdytujViewModel model) 
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Produkt = sklepBaza.PobierzProduktWgId(id); 
            model.Kategorie = sklepBaza.PobierzKategorieProduktow(); 
            return View(model);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Kategorie");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the post action you can pass just the model object and it will contain the `id`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edytuj(ProduktyEdytujViewModel model) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Produkt = sklepBaza.PobierzProduktWgId(model.id); 
        model.Kategorie = sklepBaza.PobierzKategorieProduktow(); 
        return View(model);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Kategorie");
}
```

Comment: Well it makes sense! But unfortunately if I remove _int id_ from HttpPost I get an error _No overload for method 'Edytuj' takes 2 arguments_.

Comment: check your `route` table and be sure you defined `id` as `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: I checked it and it was this way by default [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/8BovC.png).

Comment: which version of `asp.net mvc` do you use? I think not version 3 or your view is not strongly typed view?

Comment: Hello again, I have found the cause of the problem with that _"No overload for method 'Edytuj' takes 2 arguments"_ - I have deleted the Test Module which I had attached while creating the project. Right now application starts normally and thanks to your suggestions it works :). Thank you very much.